# Customer with id "customer_id" not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree

I'm using the below Braintree code in order to find a customer thru the customer_id but getting this error `customer with id "customer_id" not found`. And in order to make this work I need to replace the string 'customer_id' with a variable that represents the customer id of a customer within my Braintree Vault.

I'm kind of stuck with the variable and need some help!!

User.rb

```
customer = Braintree::Customer.find(customer_id)# this string here need to be replaced
customer_card = customer.payment_methods[0].token
payment_method = Braintree::PaymentMethod.find(customer_card)
sub = payment_method.subscriptions[0]
sub.status
```

The create method is located inside the transactions_controller.rb

```
def create
    nonce_from_the_client = params['payment_method_nonce']
    @result = Braintree::Customer.create(
    first_name: params[:first_name],
    last_name: params[:last_name],
    :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client
)

  if @result.success?
    puts @result.customer.id
    puts @result.customer.payment_methods[0].token
    redirect_to showcase_index_path, notice: 'Subscribed'

  else
    redirect_back( fallback_location: (request.referer || root_path),
                 notice: "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!")
  end
end
```

Comment: make sure there is customer_id column in your customers table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @xiaocui... I have the customer_id in my users table, since I don't have a customer table, but still returning same error `customer with id "customer_id" not found`. Any idea what I might be missing here??

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get customer_id to put to Braintree::Customer.find? Have you created customer successfully before finding. The exception may be thrown because Braintree can't find provided customer on their system. You can login to Braintree and export customer list to check whether provided id exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tai tran tuan! to o answer your questions, the customer_id is just an example from Braintree,  I need to replace the string 'customer_id' with a variable that represents the customer id of a customer within my Braintree Vault.Yes customers are created successfully via `@result = Braintree::Customer.create()`

Comment: Full disclosure, I work at Braintree,  If you need further assistance, feel free to reach out to support@braintreepayments.com

@Theopap you can parse the customer_id from the successfully created customer from the result object, for example:

customer_id = result.customer.id

You can always search for Customers outside with https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search, that will allow you to search for customers you've created in the past using multiple parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your transactions_controller.rb create method, while calling Braintree::Customer.create you can provide :id parameter to put your user id as customer id. (So you can provide your user table's id in this case)

If you not provide :id parameter then Braintree will create its own id for that customer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Katan Doshi..The Braintree customer_id is more unique and has more digts then my user_id, so I would like to just use the Barinatree customer_id instead. Any pointers on making this work?